# How to render h:message only if validation fails for the component

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, message

i have an issue with using p:messages so i am trying to use p:message for each component as follows:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <h:panelGrid id="messages" columns="1">
      <p:message for="idTxtFirstName" id="msgFirstName" />
      <p:message for="idTxtLastName"  id="msgLastName" />
      <p:message for="idTxtTitle"  id="msgTitle" />
      <p:message for="idTxtCompany" id="msgCompany" />
      <p:message for="idTxtEmail"  id="msgEmail" />
      <p:message for="idTxtPhoneNumber" id="msgPhoneNumber" />
      <p:message for="idEstNumOfUser" id="msgEstNumOfUser" />
    </h:panelGrid>                                          
</div>
```

the defaul generated html even if there are any errors is:

```
<table id="betasignup:messages">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><div id="betasignup:msgFirstName" aria-live="polite"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="betasignup:msgLastName" aria-live="polite"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="betasignup:msgTitle" aria-live="polite"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="betasignup:msgCompany" aria-live="polite"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="betasignup:msgEmail" aria-live="polite"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="betasignup:msgPhoneNumber" aria-live="polite"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="betasignup:msgEstNumOfUser" aria-live="polite"></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

so i was wondering how to render the message component if only validation fails for the component (not validation fails in general), i mean don't generate any html until there are validation errors only for the related component.

Comment: Huh? Why don't you just use a single `<p:messages>`?

Comment: @BalusC as i told you in other post, p:messages with blur event display only message for current component and clears old messages for other components, that's why i am trying to implement p:messages manually to get over this issue.

Comment: In other words, the answer in your other post hasn't solved the concrete problem at all, but yet you accepted and bountie'd it?

Comment: @BalusC, no it actually saved the messages and did what i want, it only has issue with server side listener.

Comment: Aparently your problem/question description doesn't match at all with what you actually want. In case of the previous question, that would be "I want to validate all other input fields when I blur one input field" and thus definitely not "I want to keep previous messages for other input fields when I blur one input field". There's namely quite a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `id` of the component that should be validated in the message tag. If you want to validate an input for an `<p:inputText>` it should look like this:

```
<p:inputText id="inputText" value="#{mrBean.text}"/>
<p:message for="inputText" id="inputTextMessage"/>
```

Then the message is only rendered if JSF validation fails for the component.

As I see you have chosen other ids in the `for` of the message. This should be the reason why this does not work.